# elasticsearch with angularjs no matter what I search, it always hits all data in the database

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch, dsl

Question about Querys in AngularJs with Elasticsearch.
If I just use Kibana, the result of this will be 10 hits, which is make sense.

```
POST /_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "fieldname": "Obama"
    }
  }
}
```

If I use q parameter like the official APIs describe:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihGQ7.png)
I will also get the answer by using

```
newsApp.controller('searchCtrl', function ($scope, client) {
    $scope.searchFunc = function(){
      client.search({
            q: "fildname: Obama""
      });
});
```

It will also be fine.
But when I need more:

```
newsApp.controller('searchCtrl', function ($scope, client) {
        $scope.searchFunc = function(){
          //I have tried this:
          client.search({
               "query": {"match": {"fieldname" : "Obama"}}
          });

          //I have tried this:
          client.search(
          {
            body: {
              query: {
                match: {
                  fildname: "Obama"
                }
              }
            }
         });
});
```

Then I could only get Nothing. So I don't know what kind of query I could really use??
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Qqpn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add index and use the same the query format. see logs in callback function

```
client.search({
  index: 'myindex',
  q: 'title:test'
}, function (error, response) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Yeah, q like this works fine. but if I wanna use filter or highligt querys, it is not work